# how would be time interval defining as min and max in cplex

Tags: parameters, cplex

I have defined these two parameters in my code and then, i defined Ti as an interval, how can i code these in Cplex?

tmin: availability time
tmax= delivery time, with Ti=[tmin,tmax]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write in OPL

```
using CP;

int tmin=1;
int tmax=5;

dvar interval Ti in tmin..tmax;

subject to
{
  
}
```

and if your ti is not a decision variable but a range you can write

```
int tmin=1;
int tmax=5;

range ti=tmin..tmax;
```

plus range arrays do not exist but

```
// sets 

{int} R1={1,2}; 
 {int} R2={1,7,10}; 
 
 {int} R= R1 union R2; 
 
 // Parameters 
 
 int t1[R]=[1,2,3,4];
 int t2[R]=[3,7,9,12]; 
  
 {int} T[i in R]=asSet(t1[i]..t2[i]);
 
 execute
 {
   writeln(T);
 }
```

works fine and gives

```
[{1 2 3} {2 3 4 5 6 7} {3 4 5 6 7 8 9} {4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12}]
```

Comment: Thank you, Ti is a parameter. is it remain the same?

Comment: to clarify, all of them are parameters. Ti just defined as an interveal which is defined by these two(tmin and tmax)

Comment: Then range could be enough

Comment: i do not know why it has an error.    // sets
 {int} R1=...;
 {int} R2=...;
 {int} R= R1 union R2;
 
 
 // Parameters
 
 {int} t1[R]=...;
 {int} t2[R]=...;
 range T[R]=t1[R]..t2[R];